# Android Programming - Post Method

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to send a message to a PHP code that is in my localhost. Have searched and haven't found the problem, can anyone help me?

```
package com.example.asynchttppost;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText value;
    private Button btn;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        value=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pb=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(value.getText().toString().length()<1){

                // out of range
                Toast.makeText(this, "please enter something", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                new MyAsyncTask().execute(value.getText().toString());      
            }


    } 

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            postData(params[0]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result){
            pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress){
            pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String valueIWantToSend) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/receiver.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("myHttpData", valueIWantToSend));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This is the code in localhost/receiver.php:

```
<?php
 // receive data from app's http request
 $data=$_POST["myHttpData"];
 // write data from my android app to a text file
 file_put_contents('myTextFile.txt',$data);
?>
```

When I click the button, the application stops...

I found this code here: http://mobiledevtuts.com/android/android-http-with-asynctask-example/

Comment: Are you loading from the emulator?

Comment: Is the server on the Android device, Android emulator, your development computer, or another computer?

Comment: Yes, mikeswright49 running an emulator.

Comment: petey, I tried to change the ip to 127.0.0.1 , didn't work either. But I'm not sure that that was what you meant...

Comment: Dan S I'm runnin an apache and an emulator in my computer.

Comment: You should be using 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost. See: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Morrison Chang, but my php code is in 127.0.0.1, should I move it? Where to, if its in /var/www/html?

Comment: localhost is 127.0.0.1, but you could put that ip address in place of "localhost" in your request.  If your application is stopping a good indicator would probably be in your LogCat. Also, have you tried stepping through with a debugger and seeing what line the stoppage occurs and examining the inputs? Also, make sure there is no screen output from within your async task. Hopefully something here is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to add permissions as seen here: **http://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android**

Comment: Yes, I did add it. Morrison Chang told here that I should use 10.0.2.2, instead of 127.0.0.1 , do you know anything about it? Cause my php code is in a apache server in localhost...so if I should use 10.0.2.2 should I move my php code?

Comment: He also added: http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking. You should change settings of your server so it could be visible from that address range.